# Can't SSH Into Cloud Endure Replicated VM on Google Cloud Compute

Tags: ssh, firewall, replication, google-cloud-platform

I'm having trouble SSHing into a VM I am trying to migrate to the cloud. I used the "Cloud Endure" [option from google's migration doc's.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vm-migration/using-cloud-endure)

I tried yesterday and realized in my LAN the only way to log in via SSH is if my LDAP server is running, so I enabled SSH Login via PWD and confirmed it worked with my LDAP server off and then started the replication process again.

I am having the same problem as yesterday, I don't get an error from PuTTY like refused key, or any prompts. Just "Connection Refused".

I tried adding the network tag "default-allow-ssh" to the network tags section but still same error. I pay for internet per GB so I'm hesitant to try replicating again, also I have no idea what to change next.

**Does any body have any experience using Cloud Endure and having SSH troubles after?> Suggestions or more information needed?**

The distro is Ubuntu 14 just fyi.

**Also, this could be a separate question, but is there no "Remote Console" in google cloud so that I could login as if I was local?** This seems `ridiculous` to me as it is always my backup solution if I somehow break SSH.

**Update:**

Not sure if this should work as I only have 1 other working VM in the network, but I can't ping the VM from another working VM on the same VPC. (I assume same VPC, different "project", but same account and the private IP's are the same except ending in .2 and .3 respectively) I'm new to "the cloud"..., much prefer having total control. (I can ping the public IP from my LAN)

**I tried SSH'ing into the VM via the working VM on the same VPC and it just hung, no errors.**

Comment: The ping will only work if both VMs are in the same VPC network. Generally speaking VMs in different projects won't share a VPC

Comment: No they share the same VPC, the default. I fired up another VM and tested. Ping and ssh worked from within VPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is a [firewall rule to allow traffic to your instance on port 22](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls). The fact that SSH just hangs sounds like a firewall issue. Also check the base image (the one you imported) does not have any internal firewall or iptable rules that can block SSH connections

For non Google provided images, you need to make sure to install the [Linux Guest Environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment) as well to enable GCP to communicate with your instance and transfer data like SSH keys or other metadata.

Finally, since you used CloudEndure, you can [check their FAQ](https://cloudendure.zendesk.com/hc/en-us) or [contact their support](https://www.cloudendure.com/contact-us). They offer great support and can help make sure the image they imported is properly prepared to run on the Google Cloud.

Comment: I did not know about the Linux guest environment!